# Recommendation of Dispense Amount Based on Historical Averages

Tags: statistics, prediction

I am working on creating a function to provide recommendations for the amount to dispense. I have historical data on the average daily dispense amount for each item, but I lack information on the number of dispenses made in one day. Given this limitation, how can I make an accurate recommendation? For my school project, I can assume there is an average of 4 dispenses a day and then track them to provide a recommendation based on the average divided by 4. Are there alternative approaches to address this issue effectively?